# How to add numbers in a column and insert the total to a differentcolumn

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

Let me preface this by saying I'm a complete newbie to scripting.

We have many mismanaged quota files that need their totals updated. I'd like to have a script that can calculate totals of each volume with instead of doing it mechanically every month. Please see example below.

Our quota file looks something like this:

```
/vol/vol1/NStorage1             tree    200G
/vol/vol1/NStorage2             tree    5G 
/vol/vol1/NStorage3             tree    300G
/vol/vol1/NStorage4             tree    145G
/vol/vol1/NStorage5             tree    3G
/vol/vol1/NStorage6             tree    5G
#
# vol1 total 700GB

/vol/vol2/NStorage7             tree    20G
/vol/vol2/NStorage8             tree    1G
/vol/vol2/NStorage9             tree    30G
/vol/vol2/NStorage10            tree    55G
/vol/vol2/NStorage11            tree    25G
/vol/vol2/NStorage12            tree    430G
/vol/vol2/NStorage13            tree    20G
#
# vol2 total 550GB
```

and so on....

What I am trying to do is take a total sum from the 3rd column, and add it to the "volX total ####GB" line.

I have tried to use AWK but it would only do the first section of the column and I don't know how to get it to replace the total for each column.

```
awk '{ sum += $3 } END { print sum }' < file
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the units of data in your file would always be `Gib` ?

Comment: Yes, always in Gib. We do not manage anything bigger or smaller than that.

Answer (score 1):

If the unit in your file is always be `GB`, you can use this line:

```
awk '!/^#/{s+=$3+0;print;next}NF>1{$NF=$NF+s"GB";s=0}7' file
```

with your input example, it will output:

```
/vol/vol1/NStorage1             tree    200G
/vol/vol1/NStorage2             tree    5G 
/vol/vol1/NStorage3             tree    300G
/vol/vol1/NStorage4             tree    145G
/vol/vol1/NStorage5             tree    3G
/vol/vol1/NStorage6             tree    5G
#
# vol1 total 1358GB

/vol/vol2/NStorage7             tree    20G
/vol/vol2/NStorage8             tree    1G
/vol/vol2/NStorage9             tree    30G
/vol/vol2/NStorage10            tree    55G
/vol/vol2/NStorage11            tree    25G
/vol/vol2/NStorage12            tree    430G
/vol/vol2/NStorage13            tree    20G
#
# vol2 total 1131GB
```

### update

If you want the sum to **replace** the `total` value, not `add to`, just:

```
 awk '!/^#/{s+=$3+0;print;next}NF>1{$NF=s"GB";s=0}7' file
```

Comment: first total should be 658GB, don't know why you are getting 1358GB - probably because you are also adding the commented line 700GB?

Comment: @fedorqui I thought it is required... :( `take a total sum from the 3rd column, and add it to the "volX total ####GB" line.`

Comment: It looks a bit weird, though. Anyway, now you have not one but two good solutions, so get a double big +1

Comment: Yes, I definitely need the updated sum to replace the total value. I apologize for my crappy wording.

Comment: I did use the "replace" line that you suggested, but instead of writing to the quotas file it's getting the numbers from, it echod it in the console. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Comrade1809 `awk ... file > foo && mv foo file`

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank you very much! Now to figure out what all the flags mean so I can learn from this.